# Docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296:

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a simple node application with express but I get this error:

[image]

Here's my working directory:

[image]

I ran the following command to mount my current source code directory to `/var/www` inside the node container and run node npm start to start up the app; 
but I get the error above and not sure what to do:

```
docker run -p 8085:3000 -v /home/joel/workspace/plural_docker_webdev:/var/www node -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

And I get this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"-w\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Answer (score 33):

Docker is telling you that the command hit an error.
It is trying to run the `node` image with the command `-w`.
Since `-w` is not a command, it throws this error.

This is because you have written `node` in a place you probably didn't mean to.

Your command is being interpreted like this:

```
docker run -p [port_info] -v [volume_info] node [command]
```

You can rewrite your command like so and it should work fine:

```
docker run -p 8085:3000 -v /home/joel/workspace/plural_docker_webdev:/var/www -w "/var/www" node npm start
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan but isn't that the same command I have in my question; how's yours different than mine; where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You have node written twice. Once at character 78 and again at character 97. Remove the first one.

Comment: The first node is the image name and the second one is the command that docker will run which is node npm start; My issue was with the volume mounting, node wasn't able to find the package.json file since it was up a directory more so I just ran my same command but just add /Express_website/ to give full path to package.json and it works now  thanks again so the new command would be: docker run -p 8085:3000 -v /home/joel/workspace/plural_docker_webdev/Express_website/:/var/www -w "/var/www npm start
Notice the volume mounting now includes /Express_website to point to package.json. Thanks Ryan

Comment: That may have been an additional issue. However, any arguments you are intending to pass to `docker run` need to appear before the `[container_name]` argument. In the command you posted, you have `-w "/var/www"` appearing after `node`. That is why docker is trying to run the command `-w` and giving you an error explaining exactly that. Also, `node npm start` is not a command. It is just `npm start`. You can verify this in the console.

Comment: I just tried removing the node and just leave npm start and it didn't work. I'm not sure why it forces me to specify node + args like so Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js ] [arguments] 
You're right usually just running npm start would work if working locally; I think it may have something to do with the node image and running the "node npm start" WITHIN the container? Not sure

Comment: I solved my problem by putting `[container_name]` after commands. Thanks @RyanRapp

Comment: Yes, adding container name before arguments was also throwing same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My problem was that we did not give it enough memory.
Went with the recommended minimum of 2GB of memory. turns out other resources were consuming most of it. gave it 4GB, rebooted & it works fine now.