# Docker: When running with volume (-v) flag Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to **dockerize** my first `Go` Project (Although the question has nothing to do with Go, I guess!).

**Short summary** (of what the code is doing) - It simply checks whether a `.cache` folder is present and creates it if it doesn't exist.

After dockerizing the project, my goal is to mount the **path** within the container where `.cache` is created to a **host path**

Here's my Dockerfile (Multistaged):

```
FROM golang as builder

ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /proj

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build

RUN ls
FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /proj/project /proj/
RUN chmod a+x  /proj/project
ENTRYPOINT [ "/proj/project" ]
```

EDIT: If I run something like this (as @Jan Garaj mentioned in the comments):

```
 docker run --rm -v "`pwd`/data/.cache:/proj/.cache/"  project-image:latest
```

doesn't throw an error,  but **creates an empty** `data/.cache` folder on the host with no actual (content) files and folders from the container's `.cache` directory. Although, the executable inside the container is able to create the `.cache` directory and its subsequent files and folders.

*I know, variations of this problem has been asked a lot of times, but trust me, I've tried out all those solutions.* The following are some of the questions:

1. [Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816702/docker-error-response-from-daemon-oci-runtime-create-failed-container-linux-g)
2. [A GitHub issue which looked familiar](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/297) - Still doesn't have an answer and is open.
3. [Another GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4039) - Probably the best link so far, but I still couldn't get it to work.

***The fact that removing the volume flag makes the `run` command to work is confusing me a lot.***

***Can someone please explain what's going on in this case and point me to the right direction.***

P.S. - Also, I'm running docker on a MacOS (macOS High Sierra to be specific) and I had to enable file sharing in `Docker-> Preferences -> File Sharing` with the host mount path (Just an extra information!!).

Needless to say that I have also tried out overriding `ENTRYPOINT` by trying to fire something like `/bin/sh /proj/project` which also didn't work (as it couldn't find the executable `project` even after mentioning the full path from the `root`). I read somewhere that the `alpine` image has `sh` only and doesn't have a `bash`. I am also changing the privileges of my executable `project` while building the `image` to `a+x`, which also doesn't work.

Please do let me know if any part of the question is unclear. I've also checked in my [**code here in GitHub**](https://github.com/aryak93/project) if anyone wants to reproduce the error.

Comment: Hint: what does `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/proj --entrypoint "ls /proj" project-image:latest` show?  If you remove the `-v` option, what does it show?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks . I tried the above. With the `-v` option and without it as well, it throws the following error:
```container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ls /proj\": stat ls /proj: no such file or directory": unknown.``` 

Although, as I mentioned in the question description, running `docker run --rm project-image:latest` works fine (i.e. if I try without overriding the `ENTRYPOINT`).
I still can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: What is a point for that volume `-v "\`pwd\`/data:/proj`? First, you will build binary `/proj/project` and then you will overwrite the whole folder `/proj` with host folder `\`pwd\`/data`. Do you have that binary with correct permission in `\`pwd\`/data/project`? Blind guess for better volume: `-v "\`pwd\`/data/.cache:/proj/.cache"` - it doesn't overwrite container `/proj` folder.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks. I read the updated comment. Yes, my project binary has executable permissions. Also, docker run --rm -v "pwd/data/.cache:/proj/.cache" project-image:latest didn't throw an error. I got the `Cache created` log as well. I got the `.cache` folder but I still don't get the files and folders under `.cache` folder from the container. It always create a blank folder. I `exec`-ed into the container and I rechecked whether there's a permission issue or not. The binary is able to create the `.cache` folder and subsequent files as well when I checked from inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

When you mount your working directory's subdirectory `data` to the `/proj` directory inside the container, the entire folder, including binary you've compiled and copied in there, will no longer be available. Instead, the contents of your `data` directory will be available inside your container on `/proj` instead. Essentially, you are 'hiding' the container image's version of the directory and replacing it with a directory from outside the container.

This is because the `-v` flag, with the argument you've given it, creates a bind mount and uses the second parameter (`/proj`) as the mount target.

To solve the problem, either copy the binary to a different directory (and change the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction correspondingly), or choose a different target for the bind mount.